# Christmas advent calendar

Tags: jquery

I have a vision of an advent calendar, where there are pictures of real windows with shudders, and when the user clicks on a picture, the shudders open to reveal what's behind them.

How can I do this?  I suppose I could use the primitive slideDown method in jQuery.  But is there a slideLeft and slideRight?  Or an openDoor, where each shudder rotates on an axis?

This would be one div that has a transition of opening to both the left and right at the same time.

Comment: Very cool. Would love to see the finished product!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core jQuery only has a slideDown and slideUp (one of jQuery's many unfortunate idiosyncrasies). But there's jQuery UI (User Interface), an extension to the jQuery framework, with which you can achieve this. It has a slide effect that accepts parameters for direction and speed (see documentation on http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide).

An example would be

```
$("leftshutter").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
$("rightshutter").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
```

although that might do the exact opposite.

I'm not sure what kind of motion openDoor would need. How would you project rotation around the Z axis to the two-dimensional plane? If you figure it out mathematically, there might be a way to do it using the core `.animate()` function, which animates a custom set of CSS attributes. That is, however, probably limited to manipulations that result in rectangles and not the rhombuses you might want.

Comment: Wow Marcell!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I'm familiar with jQuery-UI, and I really wanted to use it.  I guess I need to read through the documentation again to remember what all is available.

Comment: I was stunned to realize you know my name (did I mention that anywhere?), but I apologize for answering in the most basic terms and wish you a merry Christmas (I'm sure you'll be finished in time :))

Answer (score 2):

I was curious to see other solutions and I found this... I guess there aren't a lot of working examples so though I'd share.

I wrote this today: http://www.ucc.org/advent/calendar/

Modified from: http://web.enavu.com/demos/curtain/